# Append trailing slash to url in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Simple question, but I can't find any answer that works:

How to append trailing slash to url in Laravel 4?

Comment: When:  In your routing, or when you are generating a URL?

Comment: My routes are defined without / at the end because Laravel always redirects to url without it, so route won't get hit. Actually only one of my routes need trailing slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:  As timgws mentioned, this solution no longer works in Laravel 4.1+

If you comment out line 16 in bootstrap/start.php

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/bootstrap/start.php#L16

```
//$app->redirectIfTrailingSlash();
```

It should no longer redirect to the URL without the slash.

Then you can redo your route to show the trailing slash like:

```
Route::get('login/', function() { // etc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 4.0 (**not** 4.1), you should comment out line 16 in bootstrap/start.php (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/bootstrap/start.php#L16)

```
//$app->redirectIfTrailingSlash();
```

Laravel 4.1 removed `redirectIfTrailingSlash` as it can now be controlled in the `.htaccess` file (as it always should have been!).

You also might also want to change `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php` [so that generated URLs](http://laravel.com/docs/routing) have a slash at the end of them.

```
public function to($path, $parameters = array(), $secure = null) {
// ...
     return trim($root.'/'.trim($path.'/'.$tail, '/'), '/') . '/';
}
```

After changing this code, templates and code that use URL generators (such as `URL::to()`) will now generate URLs with a trailing slash at the end of the URL, which saves you an extra character in your templates!

Comment: But that would mean we'd have to change this every time the file is updated.

Comment: Well, then file a bug report with Laravel. There are many parts of the code inside Laravel that assume that there will never be a trailing slash.

Comment: I ended up making four classes which inherit from `Illuminate\Foundation\Application`, `Illuminate\Http\Request`, `Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider`, and `Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator` respectively. They have identical names in a different non-global namespace. I overrode `Illuminate\Foundation\Application::requestClass`, `Illuminate\Foundation\Application::registerRoutingProvider`, `Illuminate\Http\Request::url`, `Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider::registerUrlGenerator`, and `Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::to`. I also modified the rewriting in the ".htaccess" file.

Comment: @TylerCrompton, any chance that you could share your code on GitHub for the rest of the world, and post that as an answer?