# Laravel and Angularjs hybrid approach

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-4, frontend

I am giving my first steps in learning Angularjs so I decided to make a simple app to test my knowledge about it.

My app isn't really a SPA, because the login is made using entirely Laravel but after that the user is redirected to where my SPA resides. Hopefully this make sence.

Everything is working fine except the link that look like this:

```
http://example.com/admin#/home
```

instead of:

```
http://example.com/admin/#/home
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? If you guys need more details please say so :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I see your routes.php file?

Comment: @VerronKnowles here they are: http://laravel.io/bin/VLj9R

Comment: Would you like every thing after the /admin to be handled by AngularJS's routing?

Comment: Also, admin#/home is not going to trigger your prefix, because it isn't really a directory. If laravel wasn't in the picture, your httpd service would be looking for a file named admin. Directories end with '/'. Since we're using laravel, we can make it work though :).

Comment: @VerronKnowles Yes I would like every thing after the /admin to be handled by AngularJS routing, but in the same time keep the route group at laravel for authentication filters and stuff :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is laravel will redirect the page if a trailing slash will be found,
check this for more info
[Append trailing slash to url in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154879/append-trailing-slash-to-url-in-laravel-4)

This will work on if you are using laravel 4.0

In laravel 4.1 you can comment out the following line in your `public/.htaccess`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: I will try this when I get home. Thank you sir!

Comment: It kinda works, if i manually put the / in the url, but when it redirects from the login to the spa page the url always comes without the trailing slash.