# Angular routing with Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-4, angular-ui-router

I have a Laravel route that serves an angular app. I want it running under the `/live` folder, so:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'live', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::any('', [ 'as' => 'live.index', 'uses' => 'LiveController@index' ]);
    Route::any('{all}', [ 'as' => 'live.index', 'uses' => 'LiveController@index' ])->where('all', '.*');
});
```

The `LiveController` just makes and returns the view. This means that anything with the base-url `/live` will load the angular app.

I've set the `<base href="/app/" />` because my app is living under `public/app`, and this seems to work. However, on visiting `/live`, Angular converts the url to:

```
`live#/`
```

rather than:

```
`live/#/`
```

Here's my Angular routing file:

```
(function(){

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .config(routes);

        routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider'];

        function routes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

            // Configure app states
            $stateProvider

                .state('app', {
                    abstract: true, 
                    templateUrl: 'modules/app/app.html',                
                    controller: 'AppController'
                })

                .state('app.home', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: 'modules/home/index.html'
                })

                ;


            // Set 404
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');

        }
})();
```

Comment: And if you navigate to `/live/`?

Comment: If I navigate there, I get `live/#/`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154879/append-trailing-slash-to-url-in-laravel-4 :)